# Command to create pull request from GIT stream to stream in BitBucket

Tags: git

I am new to git, I need to command to merge two different remote streams from command line

Eg I have a `develop` branch and `master` branch , I need a command line to merge `develop` to `master` remotely in BitBucket server.

Comment: You have said bigbucket, but am I right in thinking you mean bitbucket?

Comment: I think it is possible to use git checkout <branch> on the branch you need, and then git pull -u origin <other branch>. So then you merge the two branches. I'm not entirely sure that is what you are finding, but it combines two branches, but doesn't delete them (both on the same commit, but both come from different child branches)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "remotely directly on bitbucket.org" (and not locally in a SourceTree IDE), then see "[Syncing and merging come to Bitbucket](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/02/04/syncing-and-merging-come-to-bitbucket/)"

You need to use the compare view in order to merge two branches:

[image: https://blog.bitbucket.org/files/2013/01/merge-button.jpeg]

But that would not be a "command-line".

Normally, you clone the repo locally, and then you can merge, test (locally) and push back to the remote repo.

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<repo>
git merge origin/develop
```

Any "remote merge" in command line would have to use the [BitBucket Could API](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-bitbucket-cloud-rest-apis-222724129.html#UsetheBitbucketCloudRESTAPIs-Supportedendpointsandtheirresources), but that API only involve [merge for pull requests](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/4.9.1/bitbucket-rest.html#idp2114352), not for any two branches.